# How to save retrieved JSON as object?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

How can I save the result of an HTTP request from JSON format to an object in TypeScript.

Here is my code:

Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DateTimeService } from './datetime.service';
import { DateTime } from './datetime'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  providers: [DateTimeService]
})


export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private _dateTimeService: DateTimeService){ }

  dateTime: DateTime = new DateTime();

  getDateTime() {
    this._dateTimeService.getDateTime().subscribe(data => this.dateTime = data,
      error => alert("error"),
      () => alert("done"));
    debugger;

    alert(this.dateTime.date);
    alert(this.dateTime.milliseconds_since_epoch);
    alert(this.dateTime.time);

  }
}
```

Service:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {Injectable} from'@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import { DateTime } from './datetime'

@Injectable()
export class DateTimeService{
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }
    getDateTime()  {
        return this._http.get('http://date.jsontest.com').map(res => <DateTime>res.json());
    }
}
```

All properties of `DateTime` object are undefined when I run this code. However if I don't cast the incoming data to be of type `DateTime` in my service, and use `JSON.stringify(data.time)` (for example), I'm able only to get a single property.

Comment: Your alert seems like it's not inside the function you are subscribing to.

Answer (score 2):

All your alerts are undefined, because the alerts are run before data has been retrieved.

```
getDateTime() {
    this._dateTimeService.getDateTime().subscribe(data => this.dateTime = 
    // executed sometimes later
    data,
      error => alert("error"),
      () => alert("done"));
    debugger;
 // executed first
alert(this.dateTime.date);
alert(this.dateTime.milliseconds_since_epoch);
alert(this.dateTime.time);
}
```

If you add your alerts inside the subscription, your alerts should work

```
getDateTime() {
    this._dateTimeService.getDateTime().subscribe(data => { 
    this.dateTime =  data;
    alert(this.dateTime.date);
    alert(this.dateTime.milliseconds_since_epoch);
    alert(this.dateTime.time);
  });
}
```

This is because this is asynchronous call, so code is not executed in the order they are written. If you have trouble seeing your data in your view, this is for the same reason, view is rendered before data has been retrieved, so here comes the use of [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) or `*ngIf`.

You'll have to get used to this, since we are constantly dealing with async operations ;)

So you can wrap your template inside a `*ngIf` like so:

```
<div *ngIf="dateTime">
  <!-- Your code here -->
</div>
```

which removes the div from the template until there is values in `dateTime` (we assume there will be).

The other option is the aforementioned safe navigation operator, which you could use like so:

```
{{dateTime?.date}}
{{dateTime?.milliseconds_since_epoch}}
{{dateTime?.time}}
```

Comment: Did this answer help you? If so, please consider accepting this answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235